'Failed to start GNOME Display Manager' error at start-up after deleting my Windows partition
I have recently deleted my Windows installation and only use Ubuntu. I have deleted all the partitions related to Windows and created a new one with gpart. I then mounted this data partition from the terminal. Since then, I cannot boot with Ubuntu. The bootloader is working, but has still Windows in it which just gives me a blue error. When I click Ubuntu there is the booting logo and animation and then some errors without the quiet mode:

It shows an error to start GNOME.
Using systemctl status gdm.service :
gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/.../gdm.service;static)
    Active: inactive (dead)

I also noticed that my new data partition is not shown in the recovery menu, and my main Ubuntu partition appears to be full which is not the case. Maybe it's an unfinished heavy download?

There are a few things you could try. My first thought is try opening a terminal login by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F3 ( might be F1, F2, F3, or F5). Once logged in enter
sudo apt install gdm3
and then restart.
You could also try to checking to make sure you have empty disk space by entering df -h since it's possible that there are too big of files in the /var/log directory. Another possible solution is reinstalling the gnome-shell with this command - sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell. If nothing else you could try formatting the disk and reinstalling.

I don't have any empty space to reinstall the gnome-shell. Is there a way to see why there is no space ?
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.

After an apt-get autoremove, I had enough empty space to reinstall gnome-shell, and now it works. It was indeed unfinished downloads that filled the memory.
Thanks.

Awesome! Glad you got it working.

I got same error on my Kali, the problem was my disk was full.
Solution:
Open the terminal login by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 (might be F3, F4, or F5).
Once logged, check the disk storage status by entering the command;
df -h

You can free space by deleting some files using the terminal.
Then restart your machine.
